# Spree: Should I upgrade my spree store to 2.2.0 beta?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I've built a spree store in spree 2.1.3 but one of the gem that I would like to use requires spree_core 2.2.0 beta.

```
    Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_core":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    spree_core (2.1.3)

  In Gemfile:
    spree_static_content (>= 0) ruby depends on
      spree_core (~> 2.2.0.beta) ruby
```

Can I upgrade my spree_core to 2.2.0 beta? One of my major concern is generating errors to what I've already built using spree 2.1.3 and spree_fancy theme. I've already modified the theme to my liking. Also, I'm no expert in Ruby so I'm not sure if I would be able to fix it if I end up having errors. I would like to know if I should give up on using this particular gem or upgrade my spree_core to the beta version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use master branch. Just look at that [link](https://github.com/spree/spree_static_content/tree/2-1-stable)

all spree official extensions have proper versions for various spree versions (from 0-7 to 2-1) and master for current version of spree.

To use it modify your Gemfile:

```
gem 'spree_static_content', :github => 'spree/spree_static_content', :branch => '2-1-stable'
```

and you won't have to install new version of spree.

Comment: This is for the future reference. If I upgrade the spree core from the existing website, would it cause multiple errors? or can I expect it to upgrade smoothly if all the gems I'll be using have the proper versions for the recent spree version? Or would it be faster and easier to create a new website from scratch?

Comment: I've been migrating one shop from 1-3 to 2-1 and official extensions works fine, but there were several minor errors in other extensions, nothing that can't be resolved, but you can't rely only on passing `bundle` alone, you'll have to test everything well.